# Sending more than one parameter in jquery onchange event

Tags: php, ajax

I am just getting used to jquery and have a drop down box that prompts an `onchange` event:

```
<select name="department_list" id="department_list" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value);" >
```

This works fine and the `AJAX` command called is:

```
function checkTeacherList(str) 
{
...
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?departmentName="+str,true);
...    
}
```

However I also want to use the `$user_login` variable such that:

```
<select name="department_list" id="department_list" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value,$user_login );" >
```

and the `AJAX` command is:

```
function checkTeacherList(str, schoolName) 
{
...
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+str,true);    ...    
}
```

but this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The problem is that as soon as I add a second parameter to the function call from:

```
onchange="checkTeacherList(var1);"
```

to

```
onchange="checkTeacherList(var1, var2);"
```

the function is not called. Is the syntax wrong using a comma as a separator?

Comment: you have to define what is not working. is there any error. whats does the console say?

Comment: This is just a suggestion, if you're using jQuery anyway, take a look into it's $.ajax() function, compared to native xmlhttp it's a beautiful thing

Comment: Nothing happens at all. As soon as I add the additional parameter to the onchange request ie checkTeacherList(this.value, $user_login) then the function is not called. Am I using an incorrect syntax or separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using more than 1 variable passed with GET you have to add a `&`:

```
url?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3...
```

Also you say you are using jquery, but to me it seems you are using plain javascript, if you want to make a AJAX call using jquery and GET:

```
$.get("url", {var1: value1, var2: value2}, function(data){
    //do something when the AJAX call finishes, 
    //the var data contains anything echoed by the script called.
});
```

EDIT: to follow your question.

```
onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value, '<?php echo $user_login;?>');"
```

If you are using a PHP variable in a HTML script you have to echo it, also you have to use `'` or it will cause a javascript error.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that it works with one parameter but not two. See my question edit.

Comment: edited my answer. If you want to debug this I'd recommend using firebug and track any javascript error on the console.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+str,true);
```

Comment: Yes - I did miss this but unfortunately this is not the problem. It is in passing the second parameter stops the function from being run for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
checkTeacherList(this.value,<?php echo $user_login;?> );
```

You need to echo the php variable.and try to put '&' between the two variables you are sending like

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",
"http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+str,true);    ...
```

Comment: Yes - I see that. I forgot the & and the <php echo makes sense but this does not fix the problem. Am I right in thinking that onchange="checkTeacherList(var1, var2)" is the correct syntax? ie with a comma separator? As soon as a add second parameter the function is not called at all.

Answer (score 1):

You must include `&` between the parameters, like

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+str,true);
```

Then in the calling section edit like this,

```
checkTeacherList(this.value,<?php echo $user_login;?> );
```

Comment: Thanks- you are right I missed this & but this does not solve the problem.  It is in passing the second parameter stops the function from being run for some reason. Thanks